# Connect to a Microsoft Exchange 5.5 server using Evolution

Tags: evolution, ms-exchange

I am trying to set up Evolution to connect to my company's Exchange server, but I got this error after entering the request OWA URL and credentials:

> The Exchange server is not compatible
>   with Exchange Connector.
>
> The server is running Exchange 5.5.
>   Exchange Connector  supports Microsoft
>   Exchange 2000 and 2003 only.

I read that I can use Thunderbird or IMAP if it's enabled, but that I'd lose calendar and contacts sync.  I'd rather not do that.

Is there a workaround for this so that I can get roughly the same functionality I'd get using Outlook for Windows?

Comment: None of the suggested solutions worked unfortunately, so I ended up using Windows and using Ubuntu in a VM for my development work.  Oh well - thank you anyway for the effort.

Comment: These are the issues that still hold Linux back from wider use. I have built an exchange client in php that uses webdav to talk to Exchange and it is working right up to the latest version of Exchange. Surely it cannot be that hard to include exchange support in an email client application. :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's pretty simple -- you can't.

I'm in a similar situation at my job.  DAVMail is pretty wonky -- sometimes it makes so many requests the system locks my account and I have to call tech and have them unlock it.

Sometimes it just doesn't sync.

The MAPI plug-in is even worse -- it just randomly plain doesn't work.

Running IE in Wine is a not-so-decent-but workable solution, but honestly, Outlook on Windows is the only piece of software that works correctly with Exchange.  Even Entourage (the old Mac client) uses the DAV interface (just like DAVmail) and the new Outlook for the Mac requires the latest versions of Exchange as well.

Balls vendor lock-in

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the MAPI plugin for Evolution.

```
sudo apt-get install evolution-mapi
```

I've been able to use this successfully at a previous place of employment where the only source of mail was an Exchange Server. To my knowledge contact syncing did not work - but calendar and mail services worked properly.

During the setup I needed to use the IP address of the exchange server (you can find this out by contacting your local IT or running a dig against the mail server's domain) as well as including my domain for the user login ( eg: `DOMAIN\user`). After setup of the account I needed to restart evolution for the sync to take place.

Answer (score 0):

Evolution is supposedly capable of connecting to Exchange servers, but I have tried with OWA and MAPI both with older and new Exchange servers to no avail -- if Evolution by some odd chance is able to connect, it crashes... Thunderbird is now my default mail client.

But that doesn't fix connecting to Exchange, for that you could use Davmail (http://davmail.sourceforge.net/). Davmail works as a gateway between the Exchange server and your local mail/calendar/contacts client. Davmail connect to exchange and provides local interfaces that Thunderbird and Evolution  can understand; for mail, contacts, calendar etc. And it does so really well, although a little slow at time!

Good luck!
/N